# Calling UseEffect several times causing problems

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Can someone explain why calling the useEffect hook multiple times, like in the code below, causes stale states?

```
imports ...

function App () {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    ageLevel: '',
    schoolGrade: '',
    booksCategories: '',
    numTitle: '',
    titleTypes: '',
    materialType: '',
    subjInterest: '',
    pastBook: '',
    numOfBags: '',
    bag1: '',
    bag2: '',
  })

  const handleTxtFldChange = (e, name) => {
    setFormState({ ...formState, [name]: e.target.value })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.ageLevel !== 'Adults') {
      setFormState({
        ...formState,
        numTitle: '',
        materialType: '',
        subjInterest: '',
        pastBook: ''

      })
    }
  }, [formState.ageLevel])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.ageLevel !== 'Toddlers' || formState.ageLevel !== 'Preschoolers') {
      setFormState({
        ...formState,
        numOfBags: '',
        bag1: '',
        bag2: ''
      })
    }
  }, [formState.ageLevel])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.ageLevel !== 'School-Age') {
      setFormState({
        ...formState,
        schoolGrade: '',
        booksCategories: ''
      })
    }
  }, [formState.ageLevel])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.ageLevel !== 'Teens') {
      setFormState({
        ...formState,
        titleTypes: '',
        subjInterest: '',
        pastBook: ''
      })
    }
  }, [formState.ageLevel])
  return (
    <>
      <div className='App'>
        <Container>
            <AgeLevelSelect
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
            />
            <GradeSelect
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
            />
            <BooksCategories
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
            />
            <NumTitles
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
            />
            <TypeOfTitles
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
              location={formState.location}
            />
            <TypeOfMaterial
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
            />
            <SubjOfInterest
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
              materialType={formState.materialType}
            />
            <PastBook
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
              materialType={formState.materialType}

            />
            <NumOfBag
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
            />
            <Bag1
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              numOfBags={formState.numBookBags}
            />
            <Bag2
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              numOfBags={formState.numBookBags}
            />
          </form>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Any ideas, what am I doing wrong?
All I am trying to achieve is to reset parts of the state when a user toggles Off and On questions in the form but, obviously, I am missing some basic react concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `formState` is not included in the `useEffect`s dependency array but is used in the `useEffect`s.

However if you were to add it to the `useEffect`s dependency array you would receive an infinite loop.

To solve this issue you can use the callback syntax of `setState` to not require it to be in the dependency array but still receive the current value.

```
function App () {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    ageLevel: '',
    schoolGrade: '',
    booksCategories: '',
    numTitle: '',
    titleTypes: '',
    materialType: '',
    subjInterest: '',
    pastBook: '',
    numOfBags: '',
    bag1: '',
    bag2: '',
  })

  const handleTxtFldChange = (e, name) => {
    setFormState({ ...formState, [name]: e.target.value })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormState(currentState => {
        const newState = { ...currentState };

        if (formState.ageLevel !== 'Adults') {
            newState.numTitle = '';
            newState.materialType = '';
            newState.subjInterest = '';
            newState.pastBook = ''
        }

        if (formState.ageLevel !== 'Toddlers' && formState.ageLevel !== 'Preschoolers') {
            newState.numOfBags = '';
            newState.bag1 = '';
            newState.bag2 = '';
        }

        if (formState.ageLevel !== 'Teens') {
            newState.titleTypes = '';
            newState.subjInterest = '';
            newState.pastBook = '';
        }

        return newState;
    });
  }, [formState.ageLevel]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className='App'>
        <Container>
            <AgeLevelSelect
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
            />
            <GradeSelect
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
            />
            <BooksCategories
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
            />
            <NumTitles
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
            />
            <TypeOfTitles
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
              location={formState.location}
            />
            <TypeOfMaterial
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
            />
            <SubjOfInterest
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
              materialType={formState.materialType}
            />
            <PastBook
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
              materialType={formState.materialType}

            />
            <NumOfBag
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
            />
            <Bag1
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              numOfBags={formState.numBookBags}
            />
            <Bag2
              formState={formState}
              setFormState={setFormState}
              numOfBags={formState.numBookBags}
            />
          </form>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

NOTE: I assumed `if (formState.ageLevel !== 'Toddlers' || formState.ageLevel !== 'Preschoolers')` should be `if (formState.ageLevel !== 'Toddlers' && formState.ageLevel !== 'Preschoolers')` otherwise it would always evaluate true.

Comment: Excellent this worked, although I had to change a small typo in the first if statement.  Replace the ',' by ';'. Thank you!  

**FYI:** the edit will be only visible to me until it’s been approved by trusted community members.